# Network connection halted when DPDK application running

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I'm using a PC with 2 PCIe NICs (let's call them *eth0* (Nvidia/Mellanox ConnectX-5) and *eth1* (Intel 82599ES)) currently running Ubuntu 22.04 on 5.19.0-46-generic. I'm using a DPDK application (DPDK 22.11.2 LTS) to capture UDP packets on *eth0*. Meanwhile, *eth1* is connected to the internet with a server mount via sshfs.

This setup is working fine as long as I dont use any serious traffic on *eth1* as long as DPDK is handling *eth0*.

**However, when I try to copy data via *eth1* to the server while DPDK is handling *eth0*, the network connection on *eth1* seems to time out after a few seconds (~ 3GB copied).**

The connection is not lost per se (i.e. still shown as connected), but I can neither access the mounted server, nor any websites. SSH connection is also lost when working remotely. However, **when I stop the DPDK process handling *eth0*, the network connection on *eth1* is immediately working fine**.

I'm out of ideas to debug this.

- I've had the same issue *occasionally* when using the mainboards 1GbE NIC instead of * eth1*. At some point it completely vanished and worked fine (but using 1GbE is too slow for my application).
- I've had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and older kernels.
- I've had the same issue on DPDK 20.11 LTS.
- Connection is also occasionally dropped when using remote desktop (high network load on *eth1*?)
- There's no runaway threads (CPU or memory usage) to be found in `htop` while the issue is present.
- Other symptoms are that certain applications won't even start during the issue (e.g. Chromium); likely because they try to access the arguably working network which is hanging.

My DPDK application does:

- intialize the NIC on *eth0*
- setup flow rules no the device
- start the device
- call *eth_rx_burst()* in a loop (realtime scheduled thread, 100% runtime, pinned to certain core) until stopped

**How can I debug this further?** I can reproduce the issue but I can't find anything odd and I don't know where to look anymore.